# iOS Renew Membership Early?

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-developer-program

I have just gotten an email (20th Feb) from the Apple developer portal saying that I need to renew my membership. When I checked on my account my subscription actually runs out on the 20th April. My question is, if I renew now do I loose 2 months of my subscription or is the new 12 months added onto the 20th April.

I just want to check if its worth doing or if I should simply wait until mid-April to avoid wasting part of my existing subscription?

Comment: Developers who don't renew early risk having all their apps removed from sale if there is some glitch in the renewal process (bank mistake with the credit card, etc.).  So renewing early might be a good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [iOS Developer Program FAQ](http://developer.apple.com/support/ios/program-renewals.html):

> **When will my new membership year begin?**
>
> Your renewal year will begin after your current program year ends.

That means even if you renew early, your current year will continue, and expire on April 20th as usual, after which the new year of membership will start.

Comment: Thank you BoltClock, I just read that before I posted too, just failed to see that line right at the bottom. Much appreciated.